# Exibir "teclado de emoji" usando Javascript, é possível?

Tags: javascript

Nas versões mais recentes do Google Chrome/Opera possui um recurso para selecionar emoji, nativo do navegador.

Isso pode ser feito pelo usuário clicando com o botão direito e clicar em "Emoji", em algum campo de digitação (`input`/`textarea`...). Isso exibe um "teclado" de emoji, uma caixa onde pode selecionar emojis.

---

Existe alguma maneira de mostrar esse mesmo "teclado" (esta caixa de seleção de emojis) sem a necessidade do usuário clicar com botão direito?

O  objetivo seria de criar um botão, que quando clicado, mostraria o mesmo "teclado de emoji" já presente no navegador. Acredito que para isso seria necessário alguma maneira de acionar tal "teclado" usando JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço uma forma de fazer abrir o teclado nativo do dispositivo, mas caso ninguém aponte uma resposta melhor, esta biblioteca de JavaScript pode lhe ser útil.

Ela adiciona um botão nos campos de texto que permite selecionar emojis.

https://github.com/OneSignal/emoji-picker

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: O problema é que isso exige bibliotecas externas, mas de uma inclusive. No meu caso, o uso de bibliotecas externas está sendo extremamente evitada, a única biblioteca externa existente é o Google Analytics. Não irei marcar sua resposta como "melhor resposta" (embora ela atualmente possa ser considerada a melhor alternativa), porque acredito que no futuro seja disponibilizado alguma API nativa para essa funcionalidade, _se já não existir alguma gambiarra para ativar tal teclado nativo_.